# How to mock req.session in express while testing API with jest and supertest?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

What I'm trying to do is to test a REST API endpoint that validates requests with `req.session` (set by `express-session`).

Here are snippets of my code:

`middleware.ts`

```
export const validateSecurityCode = (req, res, next) => {
  // How do I mock/spy on this "req.session.securityCode"?
  if (req.session.securityCode !== req.body.securityCode) {
    throw new BadRequestError('Wrong security code was provided');
  }
  
  return next();
};
```

`api/item.ts`

```
router.post('/item', [validateSecurityCode], async (req, res) => {
  await createItem(req.body);
  res.send({ message: 'DONE' });
});
```

As you can see, if `req.session.securityCode !== req.body.securityCode`, this endpoint has to throw an error.

Is it possible to mock/spy on `req.session` while testing the endpoint with jest and supurtest?
Below is what I'd like to achieve:

```
  it('should pass security code check', async () => {
    // " MOCK_REQ_SESSION('valid-code')" will ensure that "req.session.securityCode" will get 'valid-code'
    validateSecurityCode = MOCK_REQ_SESSION('valid-code');

    const response = await request(app).post('/api/item').send({
      securityCode: 'valid-code',
      // other request body values
    });
    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200);
  });
```

Comment: Instead of mocking parts of the transport layer, which undercuts some of the value of integration testing, why not make a request that gives you access to the value first? That's more consistent with what a real client would dk.